# Bitbucket pipeline run windows bat (batch) file remote through ssh

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Messing around with `Bitbucket Pipelines`.

I copy a directory to the remote server using `scp` and that works perfectly

```
- step:
        name: Deploy to server
        deployment: staging
        script:
            - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.9
              variables: 
                USER: Administrator
                SERVER: 145.131.29.64
                REMOTE_PATH: C:\Websites\dev.api.lekkerparkeren.nl
                LOCAL_PATH: 'release'
                DEBUG: 'true'
```

But now I need to execute a bat (batch) file on the remote host that stops IIS, copies the directory, and starts IIS again.
But how can I do this through Bitbucket pipelines.

Ive tried to use the `atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.1` but that doesnt do anything

```
        - step:
        name: Install on server
        script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.1
              variables: 
                SSH_USER: Administrator
                SERVER: 145.131.29.64
                MODE: 'script'
                DEBUG: 'true'
                COMMAND: 'C:\Websites\mywebsite.com\release\deploy.bat'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm here a few months late, but I just faced the same problem, and maybe my solution can help somebody else.

The fact is, I think you cannot execute batch files with that pipe (at least I could not). I found a lot of people suggesting building my own pipe, but that is something I left as a last resort.

What I end up doing was:

1. Install a Linux distribution through WSL on my Windows server. (This I'm not 100% sure because I tried next two steps only after I installed Ubuntu)
2. Update my .bat file to be a .ps1.
3. Then update the `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` to execute that .ps1 file.

There is a lot of documentation on how to do step one, so I will not document here, I will share what I did in the other two.

## Update .bat file to a .ps1

In your case the new file name will be `C:\Websites\mywebsite.com\release\deploy.ps1`

And the content something like this

```
Stop-WebAppPool -Name {your app pool name}
robocopy C:\Websites\dev.api.lekkerparkeren.nl {your destination path} /s /z /zb /r:5 /w:5 /np
Start-WebAppPool -Name {your app pool name}
```

You can find the meaning of the flags in [the robocopy official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and change at your will.

## Update bitbucket-pipeline.yml

```
- step:
        name: Install on server
        script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.6.0
              variables: 
                SSH_USER: Administrator
                SERVER: 145.131.29.64
                DEBUG: 'true'
                COMMAND: 'powershell.exe -FILE C:/Websites/mywebsite.com/release/deploy.ps1'
```

The mode by default is command, and that command will execute the ps1 on windows powershell. You can remove debug if is working and you don't need it.

Also I suggest using Bitbucket variables for user and server, but that's up to you.